# Can anyone please solve this python problem?

Tags: python-3.x

Write a Python code to read an integer in a file e.g 123 and convert it to words e.g One hundred and twenty three and write the result back to the same file such that your file will have "123 One hundred and twenty three " in it

Comment: what have you tried? No one is going to do the work for you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions, not for soliciting work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it on pycharm,install the inflect package and use the below code.

```
import inflect

number= int(input('Please enter a number: '))
p = inflect.engine()
print('Entered number is: ', number, p.number_to_words(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import inflect

f = open("trial.txt","r")
a = f.read()
f.close()

p = inflect.engine()
k = p.number_to_words(a)

f = open("trial.txt", "a")
f.write(" "+k)
f.close()

f = open("trial.txt","r")
a = f.read()
print(a)
```

Comment: trial.txt is the file which contains the number for example 123. So, you will get a file with "123 one hundred and twenty-three" written in it.